# clang-format: space before and after arrow operator in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I want to configure clang-format so that it puts a space before and after every arrow operators in source code.

```
(pointer)->(variable) = value;
```

will be formatted to:

```
(pointer) -> (variable) = value;
```

but I can't find appropriate style option.

I searched in clang-format style document ([https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html]) but I didn't find my desired option.

Comment: Virtually all style guides want you to do the reverse: `x -> y` --> `x->y`. Doing `x -> y` is the mark of a tyro. Look through some real source code (e.g. linux kernel, glibc source, gcc source, etc.) Even the GNU style guide does _not_ recommend this.

Comment: I find myself now curious what the OP thinks of the `(* pointer) = value` and `reference . variable = value` syntaxes.

Comment: Linus would even call that brain-dead. ;)

Comment: Please abandon this style. Force yourself to avoid it, until you realize that your code is actually now more readable and you'll never even consider it. At that time, you'll be on the winning team.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for your guide. but may you tell me why this style of code is so bad? for example in the case that a function initializes a variable of a long struct, it seems more readable to have member names separately.

Comment: It's _not_ more readable. The arrow operator `-->` [and the dot operator `.`] have some of the tightest binding. `a * b -> c` is far less readable than `a * b->c`. As I said, look at some real source code. The linux kernel [probably] has 30,000,000 lines of code. I don't think you will find a _single_ line that has such spacing. I'm pretty sure that no reviewer would allow such a line to be checked in. I've seen the spacing here in some questions here on SO. I've always found it to harder to read (I have 40 years experience writing C code).

Comment: Whenever such spacing has shown up, there has _always_ been a comment by someone to fix it. As you look at more code (e.g. a program with 100,000 lines), you'll eventually see why it is done by everyone the way it is. With that many lines, each line has to be viewed quickly. `x->y` helps that but `x -> y` slows that down. For the same reason we do: `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));` And then, `*ptr = 23;` instead of `* ptr = 23;` Or, why we do: `int x;` and then `int *y = &x;` instead of `int *y = & x;`

Comment: Many of us have been here, in our first days of programming. We get overwhelmed and start adding whitespace to everything so we can see it. We double-space every line of code, blow apart every token with more spaces, write useless comments like "this is a for-loop", hanging off the end of a for-loop... And we think it's readable because we are struggling to cope with _any_ code at that point. I'm guilty of this, many years ago when I was learning Pascal. I'm thankful to the guy who took one look at my "nicely"-spaced code and said "this is unreadable". I didn't understand why, at the time.

Comment: @CraigEstey tight binding! better to be close together, that's right. thank you so very much.

Comment: You will read and work with code written by others. Others may read and work with code written by you... The best course of action is to learn and follow conventions rather than setting out on your own.

Comment: @paddy yes, I think so. coding style is really important because it may cause or may reveal subtle problems with the code. thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: @MooingDUck one former coworker had used resharper addin on  our codebase  to make all functions calls look like  `name ()` , spaced all parents and added `const` to all by-value arguments..

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the ["Adding additional style options"](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) section of the `clang-format` documentation, not all customisations are sensible from either a conventional usage perspective, a runtime performance perspective or due to the penalties associated with invoking `clang-format` for a project.

The `->` arrow operator falls in this case for all three of the aforementioned reasons, and so no customisation key is provided for decorating it with extra spaces.

It is generally not recommended in source code to have spaces around the arrow operator. But if it is really necessary (e.g. for slideware) then the next best option would be run your script with regex to globally substitute all occurrences of `\->\` with `\ -> \`, and configure this script into your IDE. You can do this with `sed`, `python`, `ruby`, etc.